# how the empty string ("") store in memory in Java?

Tags: java

How the empty string ("") store in memory in Java?

The empty string `""` is 0 length, then how to store it in memory?

Comment: 0 length doesn't mean 0 memory footprint.

Comment: There's a memory for a reference, and memory in the heap the reference points to.

Comment: The same way any other string is stored, i.e. a `String` object with a `char[]` field. There is nothing special about the empty string, it just has a `char[]` of length 0.

Comment: To add to Andreas' comment: when an array such as a `char[]` is stored, the length has to be stored somewhere (otherwise how would the program know what the length is?).

Answer (score 1):

Borrowed from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12008937/5352399). The program prints 32 bytes for the empty string (and 0 for "" which is in the string pool).

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    long free1 = free();
    String s = "";
    long free2 = free();
    String s2 = new String("");
    long free3 = free();
    if (free3 == free1) System.err.println("You need to use -XX:-UseTLAB");
    System.out.println("\"\" took " + (free1 - free2) + " bytes and new String(\"\") took " + (free2
            - free3) + " bytes.");
}

private static long free() {
    return Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
}
```

Also, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12008745/5352399).

Comment: The amount of memory actually occupied by a string can vary at runtime depending on optimizations.