# String.valueOf(someVar) vs ("" + someVar)

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation, value-of

I want to know the difference in two approaches. There are some old codes on which I'm working now, where they are setting `primitive` values to a `String` value by concatenating with an empty String `""`.

```
obj.setSomeString("" + primitiveVariable);
```

But in this link [Size of empty Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008706/size-of-empty-java-string) it says that **If you're creating a separate empty string for each instance, then obviously that will take more memory.**

So I thought of using `valueOf` method in `String` class. I checked the documentation [String.valueOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) it says **If the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of obj.toString() is returned.**

So which one is the better way

1. `obj.setSomeString("" + primitiveVariable);`
2. `obj.setSomeString(String.valueOf(primitiveVariable));`

The above described process of is done within a `List` iteration which is having a size of more than 600, and is expected to increase in future.

Comment: you misunderstood the main point of the linked answer. You are **not** creating a new instance.

Comment: but whenever we code an empty String and the respective class is executed there will be a String object created for that empty String right?

Comment: @luk2302 Yes it is. That is what returning.

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran That is not object. String literal.

Comment: So creating these literals inside an iteration would be taking a lot of heap space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `""` that is not going to create an Object. It is going to create a String literal. [There is a differenc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489250/how-can-a-string-be-initialized-using)([How can a string be initialized using " "?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489250/how-can-a-string-be-initialized-using)) actually.

Coming to your actual question,

From [String concatenation docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

> The Java language provides special support for the string concatenation operator ( + ), and for conversion of other objects to strings. String concatenation is implemented through the StringBuilder(or StringBuffer) class and its append method.

So unnecissarly you are creating StringBuilder object and then that is giving another String object.

However valueOf directly give you a String object. Just go for it.

Besides the performance, just think generally. Why you concatenating with empty string, when actually you want to convert the int to String :)

Answer (score 2):

> Q. So which one is the better way

A. `obj.setSomeString(String.valueOf(primitiveVariable))` is usually the better way. It's neater and more domestic. This prints the value of `primitiveVariable` as a `String`, whereas the other prints it as an `int` value. The second way is more of a "hack," and less organized.
The other way to do it is to use `Integer.toString(primitiveVariable)`, which is basically the same as `String.valueOf`.

Also look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752347/string-valueof-vs-concatenation-with-empty-string) and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)